# not able to see Content editor web part in communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, communication-site

I do have a web part page in my communication site. I did activated the publishing feature of both site collection and site feature. But, I am not able to see content editor web part. Users want to add scripts

Here is the attached:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you are in a Modern site (Communication site).

By default, scripting is disabled, that why this kind of web part are not available.
To get this webpart you need to allow custom script on the site.

To do that 2 solution,

- Allow this globaly in the SharePoint central Admin (Go to SharePoint Central Admin => Settings => Custom Script)

OR

- use PowerShell to allow script only on one site collecction with the cmdlets :

  Set-SPOsite  -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

To do that, you must havee GLobal admin persmission for SharePoint

Have a look at this link : [Missing web part and features in office 365](http://mstechtalk.com/missing-web-part-features-office-365/)

Comment: Its already allow the script editor. Take a look the screen shot above

Comment: Yes you are right, the picture was not there when I replied. However, if you have active it recently, it may take up to 24hrs

Comment: If the webPart is still missing, you can test an ugly solution : Go on a classic site (who has content editor webpart), Go to Web part Catalog ([siteURL]/_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx), Dowload the "MSContentEditor.dwp" and "MSScriptEditor.webpart". Go to you communication site, Upoad these webparts in the Web part Catalog of your communication site. Now the Content Editor WebPart is avalaible.

Comment: Else, some time, when webparts are missing, there is permissions issue.

Comment: Are you sure is that work? I mean I can download from the classic site and upload to the app catalog.

Comment: yes, it work (I 've just test it), but it an ugly solution. It's not in the app catalog, you must upload it in the webpart catalogs of your site. Before, check if this webparts is not already existing in the web part catalog of your communication site

Comment: I think I hate modern SharePoint. They've made all the simple stuff we used to be able to do so much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this issue on my communication site.

As a workaround, you can open the site with SharePoint Designer 2013, find the page and edit it in Advanced Mode, then add your code under the line "`<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">`", like the below:

[image]